# Why I got extra close button on mdi child window?

Tags: c#, winforms

I got a strange problem. My mdi child form has 2 close buttons and 2 maximized buttons.

A screenshot of the problem:

[image]

I create the mdi child like this:

```
 summaryForm.MdiParent = ContainerForm;  
 summaryForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;  
 summaryForm.Show();
```

If I get rid of `"summaryForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;"`, the window style is correct. But I hope to make the mdi child form maximized when created.

Comment: Would be nice to see a screenshot!! also why not doing `summaryForm.MdiParent = this;`instead of the first line?

Comment: This code snapet is in a user control, not a form, ContainerForm is a property of the user control.

Comment: It's a bug in Winforms.  This will happen when the child is created by the parent's constructor.  Move it to the Load event.

Comment: Did you try moving ` summaryForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;  ` after the `Show()` line? Or you can set the maximize directly in the summaryForm constructor?

Comment: Sean:  I have tried moving ` summaryForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized; `, the window style is still not correct.

Comment: @HansPassant: Perhaps that should be posted as an answer?

Comment: @bucherren: Could you please post this as an answer to your own question and accept? The question is listed on the site as unanswered. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a bug in Winforms. This will happen when the child is created by the parent's constructor. Move it to the Load event.

Comment: Thanks for the information ! i d loose my time otherwise

Answer (score 0):

try this:

childform.ControlBox = false;