# WinForms MdiContainer Menu

Tags: c#, winforms, mdi

All, I have a WinForms MDI control and in it I dock several child windows. When I first did this I managed (somehow) to get rid of the window list (shown above the tabbed forms below)

[image]

I am not talking about the double window menu (on the right) I know that this is due to a bug in the WinForms control and that if you add MdiChild elements in the Load event instead of the Constructor, this behaviour resolves itsef ([see this post for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8516536/why-i-got-extra-close-button-on-mdi-child-window)).

Here I am talking about the menu strip itself, I don't want it! How do I get rid of it? Any advice is much appreciated...

Note: I am adding MdiChild forms in the following way:

```
foreach (Form mdiChild in MdiChildForms)
{
    mdiChild.MdiParent = this;
    mdiChild.Show();
}
```

where `MdiChildForms` is a `List<Form>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the possible solution:

```
public MainForm() {
    IsMdiContainer = true;
    InitializeComponent();
    this.MainMenuStrip = new MenuStrip(); // create our own menu strip
    this.MainMenuStrip.Visible = false;   
}
```

Comment: +1 Sweeet. Fairly simple really, but I assumed this could be done in the designer? There is obviously another bug with the MDI control in that this error occurred when I tried to add my own menu strip in the designer - even when I subsequently deleted this menuStrip the MDI menu persisted and there is _no_ way to get rid of it (at least in the designer). Thanks for your time.